# Why does MongoDB's positional operator ($[]) fail on a Windows machine but work on a Mac?

Tags: windows, mongodb, macos, shell, mongoose

I have the following data in a MongoDB collection named `users`:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectID("5a3903562cdc59fad5fdc098"),
    "name" : "Ana",
    "hobbies" : [
        {
            "title" : "kissing",
            "with" : "pets"
        },
        {
            "title" : "playing",
            "with" : "pets"
        },
        {
            "title" : "sleeping",
            "with" : "pets"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectID("5a3903a32cdc59fad5fdc099"),
    "name" : "Bart",
    "hobbies" : [
        {
            "title" : "hitting",
            "with" : "pets"
        },
        {
            "title" : "beating",
            "with" : "pets"
        },
        {
            "title" : "eating",
            "with" : "pets"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to replace the *pets* value of all the `with` keys with a new value like *legos*.

MongoDB's [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/index.html) for version 3.6 states the following:

> The $[] operator can be used for queries which traverse more than one array and nested arrays.

As each of the `with` keys lives inside of two separate arrays, using `$[]` should accomplish what I need to do. And on a Mac, it works perfectly but on a Windows machine, I get this error:

```
cannot use the part (hobbies of hobbies.$[].with) to traverse the element
```

Both machines are running MongoDB shell version 3.6.0. The operating system for the Mac is macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and for the Windows machine, it is Windows 10.

SO has many questions related to the positional operator and to the error I am getting specifically. But none of them address why identical operations executed on identical collections fail on Windows but are successful on Mac.

I have tried the following two commands to achieve the result I need. Both work on Mac and both fail on Windows with the same error given above.

```
db.users.updateMany({}, {$set: {"hobbies.$[].with": "legos"}});
```

and

```
db.users.update({}, {$set: {"hobbies.$[].with": "legos"}}, {multi: true});
```

You can see screen recordings of the difference [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l73swdmi8objcsv/AAA0KPUKM5KhYUKtSW_auTnma?dl=0). My apologies in advance that the text in the recording on the Windows machine is on the smaller side.

Any help to understand how to resolve this on Windows is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you run db.version() on both operating systems ? just to confirm server version are same too.

Comment: @Veeram, `db.version()` returns **3.6.0** on both machines.

Comment: Please confirm it is the same database you connect to from different systems. The error says that there is at least 1 document without `hobbies` or with `hobbies` that is not an array. Try `db.users.updateMany({hobbies:{$type:"array"}}, {$set: {"hobbies.$[].with": "legos"}});`

Comment: @AlexBlex, thank you for the recommendation but Windows still returns the same error with the` $type` operator you suggested I try. And yes, databases are identical.

Comment: Does *databases are identical* mean you have 2 databases, one on windows and one on osx, and you connect to local databases on each environment?

Comment: @AlexBlex, yes that is correct– databases are local to their respective environments. They are separate but identical. You just gave me an idea, though. I'll upload the db to mLab and point both Windows and Mac to the same db to see if I get the same error or not.

Comment: I have tried it on atlas, connecting from windows. Couldn't reproduce. So I assume it happens only when db is hosted on windows. If you can reliable reproduce it, I'd suggest to report a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Check your feature compatibility version.
By default it may be 3.4. [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/#default-values).

You need to set feature compatibility version to 3.6

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )
```

Comment: This one helps.
I first install Mongo from anaconda, which only provide v3.4, then I upgrade to v3.6 from official binary. This muse be the reason in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell but on windows it looks like for the query you have () instead of {}

Comment: Yea, it's hard to see because the text is so small but they are `{ }` not `( )`. Thanks for looking, though.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue exists on Linux too.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, MongoDB 3.6.1

Following is the output after the $[] is executed

```
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 0 }
```

P.S: I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, hence posting it here

Answer (score -1):

I check the mongodb reference, the least version is 3.6 which contains $[].